# Get value out of mat-datepicker in FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am creating a POST request to an API, and one of the fields which throws an error is a `mat-datepicker` field, since it's inside the `ngOnInit()` call(and nothing is yet selected, I guess). Fields such as `name`, `email` etc. behave well, but I'm having trouble getting a value out of the datepicker field... How could I send that value as well when submitting the form?

My attempt was this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    date_of_birth: new FormControl(new Date().toISOString(), [
       Validators.required,
       this.backendValidation.bind(this, 'date_of_birth')
    ])
   })
  }


<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="date_of_birth" formControlName="date_of_birth" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date_of_birth"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #date_of_birth></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: the value must be an object date

Comment: @Eliseo could you please show how could I implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<mat-form-field>
    Date
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date_of_birth" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
</form>

<button (click)="get()">get</button>
```

TS:

```
this.empForm = this.fb.group({
  date_of_birth: new FormControl(new Date(), [
    Validators.required
  ])
});
```

To console:

```
get(){
 console.log(this.empForm.get('date_of_birth').value);
}
```

Hope this will help you. If any issues, then I think its problem with the custom validator you have - `this.backendValidation.bind(this, 'date_of_birth')`.

Hope this works !