# How to read value of angular material date picker using reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-material-7, angular-daterangepicker

I am using the angular v-8 and angular-material v-8. I have created a reactive form inside the form I created a material date picker and when I try to read its value its gives me an object, not an exact value.

Form field code :

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Date of Birth</mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dob" formControlName="dateOfBirth">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dob"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dob></mat-datepicker>
```

Inside the typescript file, I try to read the value with

```
this.studentForm.get('dateOfBirth').value
```

but its not returning the date value. It works fine with input and other controls but with the picker not working.

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60930087/11218448

Comment: @Rohan: Can you share code on how you are initializing formControl?